# How can I get upper case at the cv2 wait key?

Tags: python, computer-vision, uppercase, opencv

I want to get the upper case key input by the wait key which in cv2.

I couldn't find the solution.

- I tried these methods but it wasn't work.

```py
pressed_key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

```py
pressed_key = cv2.waitKey(1)

if pressed_key == ord('A'):
```

Comment: Did you try `chr(pressed_key).upper() == 'A'` ? Also, with only 1 millisecond to press the key, you'll need to be quick :-)

Comment: @Demi-Lune Thank you for your comment. I think I should explain my problem detail. If I take wait key like that, the wait key just know the only small letter 'a'. So if I do like that, it always takes upper case. I should take input both small letter 'a' and upper case  'A'.

Comment: And I set the wait key to 1 because of my program`s some strange thing... Some of objects were not show when I set it to 0. So I`m using 1 now.

Comment: Same problem in Linux. cv2.waitKey returns 97 for both 'a and 'A'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
while True:
    x = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if x == ord('A'):
        break
```

As @Demi-Lune suggests, the wait time is probably to small. It works in my code because it is a small loop. I guess yours is not. So you should increase it, or set it to 0 - depending on your application.

If some things don't show up with `waitKey(0)`, you might need a code refactor. You could open a new question about that.

Comment: OMG...That was just not work on my mac environment ...I run this at the windows it worked well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not working in Linux. Problem persists.

Comment: @OguzHanoglu You're responding to an old and answered question.  It's better to open a new question, with more specifics and some sample code for your exact issue.

Comment: Because I have no particular knowledge of differences between OSses and nobody else will see your comment.